# How to create JS class object in a loop

Tags: javascript

I am have a class  in JS *job* ,now I want a simple way to create its object in a for loop, the way I trying to do this is:

```
 for(var i=1;i<=jobsCount;i++)
         {
          var eval("job"+i)=new job();

         }
```

But this syntax gives me an error as illegal life hand side assignment ,is there a simple way do this,?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to dynamically create variables in the global context, you may do this :

```
window['job'+i]=new job();
```

But I'd suggest the use of an array to avoid cluttering the global context :

```
var jobs = [];
for(var i=1; i<jobsCount; i++){ // why starting at 1 ? shouldn't it be <= ?
      jobs[i] = new job();
}
```

Comment: Over here aren't we creating a array of objects?, I don't want an array I want individual object names like job1,job2,job3,job4 and so on....

Comment: What's the problem with the array? It's even better because you only need one variable. What you want to do is not a good idea but the window solution should work.

Comment: I have already written the code using this objects at first the number of object to be created were limited,so I manually created them like var job1=new job() and so on

but now I require them to be dynamic ,if I create array I would have to modify and correct to much code

Comment: @Snedden27 The first solution ( `window['job'+i]=new job();`) builds individual variables job1, job2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jobs = [];
for(var i=1;i<jobsCount;i++)
{
    jobs[i]=new job();

}
```